# phonegap plugins showing error in CLI

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, git, cordova

I am trying to add plugins to my phonegap project. I have successfully installed node.js.

I have successfully added the cordova plugin `org.apache.cordova.network-information`. However, when I try to add git plugins using the CLI, I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Windows\System32\uuid>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git 
Fetching plugin "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.g it" via git clone 
Error: spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C :\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;F:\gowri\An\Android\ANDROID_ SDK\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin 
ENOENT at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11) 
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32) 
  at child_process.js:1144:20 at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11) 
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11) 
  at startup (node.js:129:16) at node.js:814:3
```

Any suggestions on how to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You **must** have Git installed. ( you can download it [here](http://git-scm.com/downloads) )

If you already have Git, you need to add your Git path  to your *CLASSPATH*. 
Mine is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`

Also check your all path, I don't think `C :\Ruby193\bin` need a space between **C** and **:** 
make sure you haven't duplicate path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin` I think you have him 2 times.

Restart your **CMD** and try again. Let me know if you still have issues after that.